# Laravel - How to call a method once a day automatically

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel v. 4.1 on a website. Every once in a month, I need a specific method to be called automatically for a monthly payment with Moneris. I already tested my API and it's working pretty fine. But how to call this method once a day to check if users have to pay for their monthly payment? Is it possible to do that and to call it without having a HTTP Request?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [build an artisan command](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/commands#building-a-command) and then call it in your `crontab`:

```
* 0 * * * php /usr/share/nginx/html/example.com/artisan tns:delete-old-jobs --env=production >/dev/null 2>$1
```

Have the artisan command trigger your API method.

Comment: Which implies that Laravel runs on a Linux/Unix System

Comment: OP didn't specify, but the same logic can be applied to any system.

Comment: Well, I haven't used Windows in quite a while and I am glad they finally adopted cron and the FHS. It was about time. All these annoying OS specific Paths and details finally gone.

Comment: If there are any possibilities on adding scheduled commands later, I would investigate using https://github.com/Indatus/dispatcher. It allows you to setup one cron job, then you can go and add as many scheduled tasks later directly in your app. I use it and it's great. It keeps me out of the cron tab, a place I don't like to be :) On a side note, this package is so good, it was added to the core of Laravel in version 5

Comment: Hey guys! Many thanks to all of you. I didn't know nothinig about cron jobs, but now I do with some research on internet :). Actually, I saw that CPanel has a really simple feature for adding/editing cron job. So I added my command, which was like : curl http://myurl/mypage.php. Then I added a new route and calling the appropriate method with it. So easy. Thanks to pstephan, I will take a look at it pretty soon :)